# Python - overwrite variable from another class?

Tags: python, class, variables

Simple question that i cant figure out:
I have (example) file one with this:

```
class foo:
var = 1
def bar(self):
    print(self.var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo().bar()
```

and file2 with this:

```
from testing import foo

class foo2:
    def bar2(self):
        foo().var = 2
        foo().bar()


foo2().bar2()
```

It returns 1, so no overwriting happening here.

I cant figure out how to actually overwrite the variable of the imported class instance. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446920/overwrite-variable-from-another-class-in-another-file-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448410/overwrite-variable-in-function-from-another-file) but that didnt help me.
Sorry for asking such a simple question, thanks in advance.

Comment: `foo` is a class, `foo()` is an instance. You seems to mix those notions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: class attributes and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548546/python-class-attributes-and-instance-attributes)

Comment: But i created an instance in file2 didnt i? What would the working code have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being overwritten, but you're discarding the object immediately. `foo().var = 2` creates an anonymous `foo` object, and assigns it's `var` to `2`. The problem is you're not keeping a *reference* to the `foo` object you've just created. Then, `foo().bar()` creates a *new `foo` object*, which has `var == 1` (just like *all* new `foo` objects since that's what your class does) and also calls the `bar()` member function on this *new* `foo` object, which will print `1` to console.

Try this instead:

```
def bar2(self):
    foo_obj = foo()
    foo_obj.var = 2
    foo_obj.bar()
```

Comment: Damn, i just came back to python and the difference between foo, foo() and f1=foo() always confused me. Thanks! Additional question: Are there cases where what i did ("annymous" asignment) are ever useful?

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `foo().bar()` , you're creating a second instance.

Try this:

> ```
>     test = foo()
>     test.var = 2
>     test.bar()
>  #   foo().var = 2
>  #   foo().bar()
> ```